# Is this question a good fit for your site?

Tags: discussion, migration

I was reviewing unanswered questions at writers.se and came across
https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9278/books-in-what-major-languages-are-the-least-translated-into-english which has comment that you may be able to answer it. Should I request a migration to your site?

Comment: I received the request for migration, but unfortunately the question is too old -- questions older than 60 days can't be migrated.  So you will have to ask the OP to ask it here anew.  Sorry about that.  (I'm a mod on Writers.)

Answer (score 1):

This would be a perfectly suitable question for OpenData SE! However, most questions that were migrated to OpenData SE historically didn't do too well. I guess it would be better if @Derfder posted his question again here at OpenData SE. Alternatively, if you're also interested in the topic, you could post the question and add a pointer to the original question. Of course, if you like, you can also request a migration, and we'll see how things go :)